# Symfony remove cached images using liipImagine

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I'm trying to remove cached images (which are created with LiipImagineBundle) when the source image is deleted or updated. I have already found out that it could be done using CacheManager ( https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/issues/132 )
The problem is that I can't figure it out how to use it exactly. What else do I need to add (like libraries) to my code despite these three lines:

```
    $cacheManager = $this->get('liip_imagine.cache.manager');
    $cacheManager->resolve($this->getRequest(),$pngPath,$filter);
    $cacheManager->remove($pngPath, $filter);
```

I believe there should be something like

```
    $cacheManager = new CacheManager();
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could explain me how to do that in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for example in your controller:

```
/**
* Remove an image in the cache based on its relative path and the filter applied to it
*
* @param string $path
* @param string $filter
*
* @return void
*/
protected function removeCachedImageAction($path, $filter)
{
    $cacheManager = $this->container->get('liip_imagine.cache.manager');

    // Remove the cached image corresponding to that path & filter, if it is stored
    if ($cacheManager->isStored($path, $filter)) {
        $cacheManager->remove($path, $filter);
    }

}

/**
* An action that doesn't do much except testing the function above
*
* @param Request $request
*
* @return void
*/
protected function whateverAction(Request $request)
{
    $path = //... probably from the request
    $filter = //... probably from the request

    // Remove the cached image
    $this->removeCachedImage($path, $filter);

    // ...

}
```

---

As you can see in the [CacheManager](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/blob/master/Imagine/Cache/CacheManager.php#L233-L268), the function that you'd like to use is:

```
public function remove($paths = null, $filters = null){ ... }
```

- If `$paths` is `null`, the function assumes that you want to remove the cached images for **ALL PATHS** that have been resolved with the `$filters` provided.
- If `$filters` is `null`, the function assumes that you want to remove the cached images corresponding for the `$paths` provided and that have previously been resolved with **ALL FILTERS**.
- If `$paths` and `$filters` are `null`, the function assumes that you want to remove the cached images corresponding to ALL PATHS and for ALL FILTERS. Basically ALL CACHED IMAGES.

Comment: And is it possible to use it in a function of my entity? It looks like it would work in a controller but when I try to do this in the entity I get this error:
Notice: Undefined property: Keliones\MainBundle\Entity\Article::$container

Comment: That doesn't belong in your entity (you'll hear the word model for that as well). Your model/entity holds data, it's like the list of all the ingredients you need to prepare a meal. Then, the logic (for example the functions that describe how to use the ingredients to prepare the meal or recipe) needs to stay in either an entity manager (a manager that manages your entity...) or the controller or any service or class that you want. If that makes sense...